# MySQL query returns rows in mysql but empty set in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

The following MySQL query runs in PHP without errors, but the resultset is empty.  Directly outputting the query string to a file and running the query in the MySQL client using 'source [filename]' returns several rows of results, as expected.

Is there something that would cause this query not to work with PHP? categorylinks.cl_to and smw_spec2.value_string are both varbinary(255).  Show create table indicates engine=InnoDB and default charset=binary.

Things I have tried without success:

- `$sql = preg_replace("/[\n\t]+/", " ", $sql);`
- Changing '_wpg' and 'Derp' to `CAST('_wpg' AS BINARY(255))`
- Changing '_wpg' and 'Derp' to  `BINARY '_wpg'`

I am using the MediaWiki DatabaseMysql class to execute the query and fetch rows, but it's a very thin abstraction, and I'm certain it's not the problem (see below).

```
SELECT 
    prop.name AS prop_name, prop.count AS prop_count, prop.type AS prop_type,
    val.value AS val_value, val.unit AS val_unit, val.count AS val_count
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        s_id, name, type, COUNT(foo.name) AS count
    FROM (  
        (
            SELECT
                cl.cl_to AS cat_name, s.smw_id AS s_id, s.smw_sortkey AS name, spec.value_string AS type
            FROM `smw_ids` s 
            INNER JOIN (`categorylinks` cl, `page` p, `smw_ids` s2, `smw_atts2` a)
                ON (cl.cl_from = p.page_id AND 
                    p.page_title = s2.smw_title AND 
                    s2.smw_id = a.s_id AND 
                    a.p_id = s.smw_id)
            LEFT JOIN `smw_spec2` spec ON s.smw_id = spec.s_id
        )

        UNION ALL           

        (
            SELECT 
                cl.cl_to AS cat_name, s.smw_id AS s_id, s.smw_sortkey AS name, '_wpg' AS type
            FROM `smw_ids` s 
            INNER JOIN (`categorylinks` cl, `page` p, `smw_ids` s2, `smw_rels2` a)
                ON (cl.cl_from = p.page_id AND 
                    p.page_title = s2.smw_title AND 
                    s2.smw_id = a.s_id AND 
                    a.p_id = s.smw_id)
        )
    ) AS foo

    WHERE foo.cat_name = 'Derp'
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY count DESC 
    LIMIT 10
) AS prop


INNER JOIN

(
    SELECT 
        bar.p_id AS p_id, bar.value AS value, bar.unit AS unit, COUNT(bar.value) AS count,
        IF( @prev != p_id, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, 
        @prev := p_id 
    FROM (  
        (SELECT a.p_id AS p_id, a.value_xsd AS value, a.value_unit AS unit FROM `smw_atts2` a)
            UNION ALL
        (SELECT r.p_id AS p_id, s.smw_sortkey AS value, NULL AS unit
            FROM `smw_rels2` r INNER JOIN `smw_ids` s ON r.o_id = s.smw_id)
    ) AS bar

    GROUP BY value, unit
    ORDER BY count DESC

) AS val    
ON prop.s_id = val.p_id

WHERE val.rank <= 50

ORDER BY prop_count DESC, prop_name, val_count DESC, val_value
```

Edit: The following test script outputs nothing. query.sql contains exactly the query above, written to file immediately preceding the mysql_query() call in MediaWiki's database class.

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('mediawiki', $db);

$res = mysql_query(file_get_contents("query.sql"), $db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
echo mysql_error($db);
```

Edit: I imported a huge database dump and afterwards, when I loaded the PHP page, there was a noticeable wait that seemed to indicate that the query was running, but still no results showed.  I ended up reworking the query, and I no longer have this problem.

Comment: if the query is executing it's probably not the problem. Please post the PHP code as well.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors?  Did you try outputting `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Are you sure it's 1. The same **exact** query? 2. The same **exact** server?  The same user (for permissions)?

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't like the UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to detect and report errors better:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('mediawiki', $db);

$res = mysql_query(file_get_contents("query.sql"), $db);
if (!$res) {
  print "SQL Error ".mysql_errno().":".mysql_error().", from query: '".file_get_contents("query.sql")."'";
} else {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after `mysql_connect`:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
```